# Python match statement with enum

Tags: python, enums, switch-statement, case, enumeration

I'm trying to match "header" to one of the header types in my ENUM class. I've tried header to match Header.PROFILE_NAME, Header.PROFILE_NAME.name, Header.PROFILE_NAME.*name*. However none of these worked so far. Can't find a lot of information about it either. Hope someone can help me out on this one. Cheers in advance.

```
from enum import Enum

class Header(Enum):
    PROFILE_NAME = None
    FIRSTNAME = None
    LASTNAME = None    
    EMAIL = None
    PHONE = None
    STREET = None
    HOUSE = None
    ADDRESS2 = None
    CITY = None
    STATE = None
    COUNTRY = None
    CARD_TYPE = None
    CARD_NUMBER = None
    CARD_EXP_MONTH = None
    CARD_EXP_YEAR = None
    CARD_CVV = None
```

```
    def setProfiles():
        with open('profiles.csv', 'r') as profilesFile:
            profiles = csv.reader(profilesFile)

            # Sets CSV header name to index
            for index, profile in enumerate(profiles):
                if(index == 0):
                    for index, header in enumerate(profile):
                        match header:
                            case Header.PROFILE_NAME.name:
                                print("profile")
                                #Header.PROFILE_NAME.value = index
                            case Header.FIRSTNAME.name:
                                print("firstn")
                                #Header.FIRSTNAME.value = index
                            case Header.LASTNAME.name:
                                print("last")
                                Header.LASTNAME._value_ = index
                            case Header.EMAIL:
                                Header.EMAIL._value_ = index
                            case Header.PHONE:
                                Header.PHONE._value_ = index
                            case Header.STATE:
                                Header.STATE._value_ = index
                            case Header.HOUSE:
                                Header.HOUSE._value_ = index
                            case Header.ADDRESS2:
                                Header.ADDRESS2._value_ = index
                            case Header.CITY:
                                Header.CITY._value_ = index
                            case Header.STATE:
                                Header.STATE._value_ = index
                            case Header.COUNTRY:
                                Header.COUNTRY._value_ = index
                            case Header.CARD_TYPE:
                                Header.CARD_TYPE._value_ = index
                            case Header.CARD_NUMBER:
                                Header.CARD_NUMBER._value_ = index
                            case Header.CARD_EXP_MONTH:
                                Header.CARD_EXP_MONTH._value_ = index
                            case Header.CARD_EXP_YEAR:
                                Header.CARD_EXP_YEAR._value_ = index
                            case Header.CARD_CVV:
                                Header.CARD_CVV._value_ = index

                # Creates profile and sets info
                else:
                    #print(Header.PROFILE_NAME)
                   # print(Header.FIRSTNAME)
                    createProfile = Profile()
                    for index, info in enumerate(profile):
                        match index:
                            case index if index == Header.PROFILE_NAME:
                                createProfile.profileName = info
                            case index if index == Header.FIRSTNAME:
                                createProfile.firstName = info
                            case index if index == Header.LASTNAME:
                                createProfile.lastName = info
                            case index if index == Header.EMAIL:
                                createProfile.email = info
                            case index if index == Header.PHONE:
                                createProfile.phone = info
                            case index if index == Header.STREET:
                                createProfile.street = info
                            case index if index == Header.HOUSE:
                                createProfile.house = info
                            case index if index == Header.ADDRESS2:
                                createProfile.address2 = info
                            case index if index == Header.CITY:
                                createProfile.city = info
                            case index if index == Header.STATE:
                                createProfile.state = info
                            case index if index == Header.COUNTRY:
                                createProfile.country = info
                            case index if index == Header.CARD_TYPE:
                                createProfile.cardType = info
                            case index if index == Header.CARD_NUMBER:
                                createProfile.cardNumber = info
                            case index if index == Header.CARD_EXP_MONTH:
                                createProfile.cardExpiryMonth = info
                            case index if index == Header.CARD_EXP_YEAR:
                                createProfile.cardExpiryYear = info
                            case index if index == Header.CARD_CVV:
                                createProfile.cardCVV = info
```

Comment: print the value of `header` before the match case statement

Comment: @AlwaysSunny the print header is exactly the same as the enum names

Comment: By setting every value to `None`, you have one member (`PROFILE_NAME`) and several aliases for that one member.  Use `auto()` instead.

Comment: Yeah you're right @EthanFurman. Works now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `match` statement will work directly with enums, so convert your header into an enum first:

```
for index, header in enumerate(profile):
    header = Header[header.upper()]  # or whatever is needed to match the name
    match header:
        ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. With  header = Header[header.upper()] it gives same output as the others: 
profile
profile
profile
profile
profile
profile
profile
profile
profile
profile
profile
profile
profile
profile
profile
profile

Comment: Works now together with @EthanFurmans comment above. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Would you mind extending your sample code with a case statement ? I'm trying to figure out what to use there...